# how to extract string appears after one particular string in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am working on a script where  I am grepping  lines that contains -abc_1.
I need to extract  string that appear just after this string as follow :

```
option : -abc_1 <some_path>
```

I have used following code :

```
grep "abc_1" | awk -F " " {print $4}
```

This code is failing if  there are more spaces used between string , e.g :

```
   option :   -abc_1 <some_path>
```

It will be helpful  if I can extract the path somehow without bothering of spaces.
thanks

Comment: Are all your lines just 4 fields? Does `<some_path>` have spaces in it? Also, you don't need to specify field separator to single space. By default it handles once or more spaces for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo 'option :   -abc_1 <some_path>' | awk  '/abc_1/ {print $4}'
<some_path>
```

If you do not specify field separator, it uses one ore more blank as separator.
PS you do not need both `grep` and `awk`

Answer (score 0):

With sed you can do the search and the filter in one step:

```
sed -n 's/^.*abc_1 *: *\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

The `-n` option suppresses printing, but the `p` command at the end still prints if a successful substitution was made.

Comment: @John1024 : ur solution was easy and it worked for me .. thanks ! :)

Comment: John1024 added a solution here , I don't know why he deleted his answer :S

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne ' print $1 if(/-abc_1 (.*)/)' your_file
```

Tested [Here](http://ideone.com/7fiRDl)
Or if you want to use awk:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i="-abc_1")print $(i+1)}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

try this grep only way:

```
grep -Po '^option\s*:\s*-abc_1\s*\K.*' file
```

or if the white spaces were fixed:

```
grep -Po '^option : -abc_1 \K.*' file
```

Comment: HI All , thanks for ur replies , in my command I just removed -F " " and it worked absolutely fine . :)